# Including content of wicket page into wicket panel

Tags: java, wicket, panel, html

in my project i've faced a problem with wicket panels. Suppose we have a ready page which extends WebPage

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {
  public MyPage(){
    add(new Label("some id","Hello"));
  }
}
```

and Panel which extends Panel

```
 public class MyPanel extends Panel{
  public MyPanel(){
    // here need to add content of MyPage
    // for example : inclide(new MyPage())
  }
}
```

how can i include my page into panel, or how can i include content of page into panel?

Comment: Why closing? I got same problem of understanding that when I come as new to project and see the wanted content on page and want it to panel, how you do it. Very relevant and ok question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split Mypage into a page and a panel, reuse this new panel in MyPanel.

Answer (score 1):

**First idea**: Don't. Wicket is component component-tree based. These are two main advantages of the framework. Don't break these.

**Second idea**: If you really really really want to... supply the content to the Panel by it's constructor. Wicket is Java and Java is object oriented. Just pass your objects around...

**Third idea**: With Wicket >= 1.5, use the Wicket event system to trigger changes in your target-objects.